# inotify error on WSL

Tags: windows-subsystem-for-linux, inotify

I'm running the following command:

```
echo fs.inotify.max_user_watches=524288 | sudo tee -a /etc/sysctl.conf && sudo sysctl -p
```

and getting this error:

```
sysctl: cannot stat /proc/sys/fs/inotify/max_user_watches: No such file or directory
```

I'm not sure what to do about this. I'm running WSL on Windows 10 Build 1709, OS Build 16299.309

Answer (score 0):

`max_user_watches` was not implemented in 1709. It apperars to be fixed in 1803. For more details you can refer to this bug:
https://github.com/Microsoft/WSL/issues/1705